# How do you query the background color of a ttk.Frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I know how to query the background color of a `tk.Frame` using `tk.Frame()['background']` but I don't know how for a `ttk.Frame`.

**How do you query the background color of a ttk.Frame?**

Answer (score 0):

To find out what background a Ttk frame uses by default, you need the [`lookup`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.lookup) method on the `Style` class (the background is defined by the style, not directly by the widget's configuration options):

```
from tkinter import ttk

print(ttk.Style().lookup("TFrame", "background"))
```

Note that the token returned may be a *named* color on the platform you're on. For example, on my system it is `systemWindowBody` (which in Tcl's binding I know how to resolve to a physical color but I'm not experienced enough with Tkinter to say how to do it). It works just like any other color when it comes to using it though.

Comment: Alas, you have to know that `TFrame` is the right token to use there. It's not documented _or_ discoverable. This really sucks.

Comment: you are right that it is not officially documented how to get the "TFrame" name. But I do know from TkDocs.com and his book "Modern Tkinter for Python" that you can get the name `TFrame` via: `ttk.Frame().winfo_class()`.

Comment: In the comments, can you provide how to resolve the named color to a real color in tcl code?

Comment: (I ask because I am trying to use the color 'SystemButtonFace' to paint an image but `image.put('SystemButtonFace', (0,0))` throws a tcl error `_tkinter.TclError: can't parse color "SystemButtonFace"`.)

Comment: @Trevor That the class is the same as the style element token isn't documented; they're formally different (because you can do many more funky things with style tokens).

Comment: In Tcl code, you use `winfo rgb . $theColor`. It returns a three-element list of numbers in the range 0–65535, representing the R, G and B channels for that color. (That's the real underlying color model of X11.) You typically just divide the channels by 256 to get a usable 8-bit value. Composing back into a _usable_ color is messy; if you've already got a color name, don't bother converting before using it unless you need something based off it (e.g., 10% lighter or darker).